# failed to load webpage with error unsupported url IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, moodle

I have the following problem:

In the Moodle application there is a personalized screen to access some courses, for this a "mustache" file was added to the Moodle code with the following code:

```
 <ion-list >

        <%#Cursos%>

        <%#.%>

        <ion-card style="height: 50%;">

            <img alt="Silhouette of mountains"  src="<%wwwroot%>/theme/almondb/pix/portada.jpg" />

            <ion-card-header>

              <ion-card-title><%fullname%></ion-card-title>

              <ion-card-subtitle><%shortname%></ion-card-subtitle>

            </ion-card-header>

            <ion-card-content>

                <ion-list>

                    <a href="moodlemobile://<%wwwroot%>?redirect=/course/view.php?id=<%id%>" data-open-in="app" style="text-decoration: none;">

                        <ion-item lines="inset" detail="true">

                            <ion-label>

                                <%fullname%>

                            </ion-label>

                        </ion-item>

                    </a>

                </ion-list>

            </ion-card-content>

          </ion-card>

        <%/.%>

    <%/Cursos%>

    </ion-list>
```

Custom URLs were used to achieve this. On Android the application works correctly, when you click it takes you to the course screen, however, on IOS it gives an error: "failed to load webpage with error unsupported url"

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNWek.jpg)

I have tried the following solutions that I found in other forums

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * data:;">

preference name="WKPort" value="8080"
preference name="UseScheme" value="false"
 <allow-navigation href="moodlemobile:*" />
```

But none of them have worked.